# Unable to process Binding in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I made a little example of what I am trying to do [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dethdoll/Hc34y/1/)

I am a newbie in knockout, just started working on it since yesterday. So I get this error when I run the code.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return itemcarousel }"
Message: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return markerNumber }"
Message: markerNumber is not defined
```

Below is the code I am currently using:

```
// Sends the latitude and longitude to the controller to find closes franchises
$.ajax({
       url: '{{ URL::action('frontend_getLocation') }}',
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'JSON',
       data: {'latitud': lat, 'longitud': lgn}
     }).done(function(data) {   

     //The order of elements in the array id=0, distance=1, region=2, town=3, address=4, postalcode=5, phone=6
     var itemCarouselList = [];
     for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {      

     var temp = new fillingData(
                                i+1, 
                                data[i][1], 
                                data[i][3], 
                                data[i][4], 
                                data[i][2], 
                                data[i][5], 
                                data[i][6] ); 

        console.log(temp);
        itemCarouselList.push(temp);
     }  
     console.log(itemCarouselList);


     var viewModel = {
                      itemcarousel: ko.observableArray([ itemCarouselList ])        
                     };   

     ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

     });


     function fillingData(markerNum, km, kotown, koaddress, koregion, kopostalcode, kophone) {
         var self = this;
         self.markerNumber = markerNum;
         self.kilometers = km;
         self.town = kotown;
         self.address = koaddress;
         self.region = koregion;
         self.postalcode = kopostalcode;
         self.phone = kophone;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you initialized your observableArray. It just accepts and array you don't need to wrap it in [] another array

```
var viewModel = {
    people: ko.observableArray(
        itemCarouselList

        //new fillingData(33, 300), //{ markerNumber: 33, kilometers: 300 },       
        //new fillingData(12, 666)  //{ markerNumber: 32, kilometers: 400 }        
    )        
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qcnhT/1/)

Comment: Thank You! This was the only thing I was struggling with